# Python: Read CSV and write to file using a custom format

Tags: python, csv

I have this .csv file ...

```
id,first_name,last_name,email,date,opt-in
1,Jimmy,Reyes,jreyes0@macromedia.com,12/29/2016,FALSE
2,Doris,Wood,dwood1@1und1.de,04/22/2016,
3,Steven,Miller,smiller2@go.com,07/31/2016,FALSE
4,Earl,Parker,eparker3@ucoz.com,01-08-17,FALSE
5,Barbara,Cruz,bcruz4@zdnet.com,12/30/2016,FALSE
```

**I want to read the above shown csv file, transform data, and finally write the data in another text file, which should look like this ....**

```
1,<tab>"first_name"="Jimmy","last_name"="Reyes","email"="jreyes0@macromedia.com","date"="12/29/2016","opt-in"="FALSE"
2,<tab>"first_name"="Doris","last_name"="Wood","email"="dwood1@1und1.de","date"="04/22/2016,,"opt-in"="0"
```

Also, If the opt-in value is empty, its should print "0".

Here is my code so far ....

```
import csv
import time

# Do the reading
with open('my-scripts/mock.csv', 'r') as f1:
 #next(f1, None)  # skip the headers
 reader = csv.reader(f1)
 new_rows_list = []
 for row in reader:
   if row[5] == '':
      new_row = [row[0],'\t',row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], '0']
      new_rows_list.append(new_row)
   else:
      new_row = [row[0],'\t',row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5]]
      new_rows_list.append(new_row)   
 f1.close()   # <---IMPORTANT

# Do the writing
newfilename = 'my-scripts/ftp_745198_'+str(int(time.time()))
with open(newfilename, 'w', newline='') as f2:
 writer = csv.writer(f2, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
 writer.writerows(new_rows_list)
 f2.close()
```

The above code is generating this output, which is not what I exactly want ... **I am unable to figure out how to print column names in each row as shown above in the desired output ...!**

```
"id","  ","first_name","last_name","email","date","opt-in"
"1","   ","Jimmy","Reyes","jreyes0@macromedia.com","12/29/2016","FALSE"
"2","   ","Doris","Wood","dwood1@1und1.de","04/22/2016","0"
"3","   ","Steven","Miller","smiller2@go.com","07/31/2016","FALSE"
"4","   ","Earl","Parker","eparker3@ucoz.com","01-08-17","FALSE"
"5","   ","Barbara","Cruz","bcruz4@zdnet.com","12/30/2016","FALSE"
```

**New CSV**

```
id,first_name,last_name,email,date,opt-in,unique_code
1,Jimmy,Reyes,jreyes0@macromedia.com,12/29/2016,FALSE,ER45DH
2,Doris,Wood,dwood1@1und1.de,04/22/2016,,MU34T3
3,Steven,Miller,smiller2@go.com,07/31/2016,FALSE,G34FGH
4,Earl,Parker,eparker3@ucoz.com,01-08-17,FALSE,ASY67J
5,Barbara,Cruz,bcruz4@zdnet.com,12/30/2016,FALSE,NHG67P
```

**New expected output**

```
ER45DH<tab>"id"="1","first_name"="Jimmy","last_name"="Reyes","email"="jreyes0@macromedia.com","date"="12/29/2016","opt-in"="FALSE"
MU34T3<tab>"id"="2","first_name"="Doris","last_name"="Wood","email"="dwood1@1und1.de","date"="04/22/2016,"opt-in"="0"
```

I will really appreciate any help/ideas/pointers.

Thanks

Comment: you need '<print tab>' or tab?

Comment: I need tab '\t'

Comment: Curious, what makes you say the `f1.close()` is important?

Comment: @glibdud The file I am opening for reading has about 50 columns and contains about 150K rows. So just to be on safer side, I am closing it explicitly so that I don't get any out of memory errors. Although I read somewhere that, this is now not required, as its closed by default.

Comment: @PuneetSharma Yeah, as long as you use the `with open...` construct, it should be closed automatically when you exit the block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Initially extract the header as a new list.
- Then append header with each row elements as a string.
- Write it to the file.

Please try this code,

```
import csv

with open('newfilename.csv', 'w') as f2:
    with open('mycsvfile.csv', mode='r') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        for i,rows in enumerate(reader):
            if i == 0:
               header = rows 
            else:
                if rows[5] == '':
                   rows[5] = 0;
                pat = rows[0]+'\t'+'''"%s=%%s",'''*(len(header)-1)+'\n'
                print pat
                f2.write(pat % tuple(header[1:]) % tuple(rows[1:]))
    f2.close()
```

**Output:**

```
1   "first_name=Jimmy","last_name=Reyes","email=jreyes0@macromedia.com","date=12/29/2016","opt-in=FALSE",
2   "first_name=Doris","last_name=Wood","email=dwood1@1und1.de","date=04/22/2016","opt-in=0",
3   "first_name=Steven","last_name=Miller","email=smiller2@go.com","date=07/31/2016","opt-in=FALSE",
4   "first_name=Earl","last_name=Parker","email=eparker3@ucoz.com","date=01-08-17","opt-in=FALSE",
5   "first_name=Barbara","last_name=Cruz","email=bcruz4@zdnet.com","date=12/30/2016","opt-in=FALSE",
```

Please let me know in terms of any queries.

Comment: Thanks @Karthikeyan KR. I changed the following line to produce output according to my specifications and all worked great ... Many thanks for your help.

`pat = rows[0]+'\t'+'''"%s"="%%s",'''*(len(header)-1)+'\n'`

Comment: Quick question. How do I not add a comma  after the last value ?

Comment: Please change to the following pat = rows[0]+'\t'+'''"%s"="%%s",'''*(len(header)-2)+'''"%s"="%%s"\n'''

Comment: Thanks, Now I am getting a weird error ...
`File "my-scripts/filecon.py", line 21, in <module>
    f2.write(pat % tuple(header[1:]) % tuple(rows[1:]))
  File "c:\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 112-113: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: It's​ an Unicode error . You may have foreign characters. So try to encode the string in UTF-8 format.

Comment: Thanks @Karthikeyan for your insights. This change did the trick `with open(newfilename, 'w',encoding='utf-8') as f2:`

Comment: My requirements changed slightly. Now I want to print the value of last column in the source file as the first value in target file. Please see above, I have appended the details to the original question. Can you please help ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could keep the header in a list, then use the the list (like first_name, etc.) to match the elements in the followed lines (like Jimmy, etc.) to generate the output you want ("first_name"="Jimmy").

Comment: Thanks @Gang Yes, I was thinking of that approach, but I have around 50 columns. Doing it manually is a bit tedious, so I was thinking there must be some other more quicker/faster/efficient way...?

Comment: @PuneetSharma, as soon as the number of columns is fixed, a loop should do the job as you expects, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, save the header into a variable. For example:

```
for i,row in enumerate(reader):
    if i == 0:
        header = row
    else:
        new_row = [row[0],'\t'] + ['%s=%s' % (header[j],row[j]) for j in range(1,6)]
        ....
...
```

Secondly, code such as `[row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5]]` can be simplified into [row[i] for i in range(1,6)] ([generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators))

Thridly, [format](https://wiki.python.org/moin/StringFormatting) is a good tool:
`print('"%s"="%s"'% (header[1],row[1]))` will output `"first_name"="Jimmy"`

Use this knowledge and consider how to make it work.

Comment: Thanks @Zealseeker, I tried your suggestions, I am getting this error,  `header = row.split(',')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' `

Comment: @PuneetSharma Sorry to have mistaken you. row was already the list of header. So you don't need to split it and just `header=row` is enough. Then you can use `header[1]`,`header[2]` to get `first_name` and `last_name`. I'll revise my answer